# Sublime Text 2 theme from this screensot

Tags: sublime-text-2, themes, color-theme

Just found a screen of a fresh looking dark SB2 theme, file is of literate coffeescript:

[image]

If anyone recognises it can you answer with a package name.

Comment: Check your lucky [here](http://colorsublime.com/) !!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a guessing game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching (I used the distinctive lime green for `null`) I've found it: **[Brilliance Black](http://colorsublime.com/theme/Brilliance_Black)**.